# Python: Parse a CSV column as a row and column index for a np.array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

My CSV file is formatted as such :

```
Id,Prediction
r1_c1,1
r3_c1,3
...
```

When I read the csv file as such :

```py
df = pd.read_csv('data/data_train.csv', delimiter=',')
```

I can get a matrix of size (N,1), where N is the number of values present in my input CSV file. Do notice that there are some missing values inside my input CSV file, therefore I cannot do a simple `np.reshape`

Is there a fancy function or procedure, within `pandas` or `np` that fills a matrix A such that `A[i][j] = v_ij`, where `v_ij` is the value with associated 'Id' equal to `ri_cj` ?

One could do it evidently with a for loop, but consider when the size of the input CSV file is rather large... one would be interested in leveraging the parallelism/vectorization implemented in `numpy`, for example. I couldn't describe my problem with keywords, so apologies if I couldn't find the associated documentation.

Answer (score 0):

First, while reading csv file with `pd.read_csv` read `Prediction` column as pre-defined `dtype` (in the case of this example it's `np.int32`) just to make it more efficient.

Then run the fallowing code:

```py
# Parse Id column string values as integer pairs of output array indices.
indices = np.empty((len(df), 2), np.int32)
for i, id_string in enumerate(df.Id):
    id_parts = id_string.split('_')
    indices[i, :] = int(id_parts[0][1:]), int(id_parts[1][1:])

# Infer shape of output array (OPTIONAL: used if output shape is not given).
n, m = np.max(indices, axis=0) + 1

# Create predictions output array with the same dtype.
out = np.zeros((n, m), df.dtypes.Prediction)

# Assign Prediction column values.
out[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]] = df.Prediction
```

Small test data:

```
    Id  Prediction
0   r0_c2   5
1   r1_c1   8
2   r2_c0   7
```

Output (without specifying output shape `(n, m)` ):

```
[[0 0 5]
 [0 8 0]
 [7 0 0]]
```

I've also timed-it using `%%timeit` function while running 900000 rows of data with output shape of `(1000, 1000)` and here are the results:

*1 loop, best of 3: 1.61 s per loop*

I hope this answers your question, good luck!